# Every surjective homomorphism from a fundamental group of a connected and compact manifold to itself is an isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, finite-groups

I can't understand why every surjective homomorphism from a fundamental group of a connected and compact manifold to itself is an isomorphism?
Is there any classification fore such groups?

Comment: Every finitely presented group is the fundamental group of some compact 4-manifold. So are you saying every finitely presented group has this property? Interesting.

Comment: Such groups are called *Hopfian*. Fundamental groups of geometric 3-manifolds
are residually finite and therefore Hopfian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such groups $G$ are called [*Hopfian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_group). Certainly not all finitely-generated groups are Hopfian. For a simple counterexample consider the groups 
$BS(m,n) = \langle b,s\mid s^{-1}b^ms = b^n\rangle$
with $2$ generators and $1$ relation constructed by Baumslag and Solitar for certain $(m,n)$, e.g., $(m,n)=(2,3)$. Actually $BS(m,n)$ is Hopfian if and only if $m,n$ equals $\pm 1$, or $m$ and $n$ have the same set of prime divisors.

By Michal's remark these groups arise as the fundamental group of a connected compact $4$-manifold. So the claim in the title is not true.